# Is there an alternative to HTML's classes in Android layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

In web development, it is possible to set a `class` attribute to some HTML elements (e.g. buttons), so that you can couple some commands to the elements that have this class only (e.g. js listeners, css styles etc..).

I want to do something similar in Android. I have a couple of Buttons and I want to set some listeners to work the same way on all of them. I want to use `setOnTouchListener`, and this cannot be simply added to the layout file the same way as `android:onClick`. 
The only way I know of, is by defining an `OnTouchListener` and then individually do something this:

```
Button button1  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
Button button3  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

Then

```
button1.setOnClickListener(myOnTouchListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(myOnTouchListener);
button3.setOnClickListener(myOnTouchListener);
```

Is there any other way to do that? optimally I want to do something similar to how such things are done in JQuery (e.g. `$(".my-buttons").setListener(...);`)

The point is that I want to avoid having to explicitly say which buttons using `R.id` or whatever

Comment: Iterate over a collection of ids? I mean, this is Java UI programming, not HTML/JS.

Comment: My question is whether there is a way to do it without using its ID.. Of course Java UI programming could be very different, but there could be a trick that I don't know about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) may be helpful to you. It has `@OnClick` annotation which supports multiple IDs in a single binding for common event handling. For example in activity:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    // Use "injected" views...
}

@OnClick({ R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3 })
public void handleButtonClick(Button button) {
    // handle clicks
}
```

To apply common `onTouchListener` inject buttons in `List` and define `ButterKnife.Setter` action:

```
@InjectViews({ R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3 })
List<Button> buttons;

static final ButterKnife.Setter<Button, OnTouchListener> SETTER = new ButterKnife.Setter<Button, OnTouchListener>() {
    @Override
    public void set(Button view, OnTouchListener value, int index) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(value);
    }
};
```

Anywhere after `Butterknife.inject(this)` apply `onTouchListener`:

```
ButterKnife.apply(buttons, SETTER, onTouchListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

you may iterate through whole layout and checking `instanceof`, but if you only care for `OnClickListener` you may use XML implementation

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="clicked" />
```

Button will fire `clicked(View v)` method inside `Activity` to which is attached (or throw an exception if method is miss)... you may just implement `OnClickListener` to `Activity` and in XML straight use `android:onClick="onClick"`. inside `onClick` you may also use `switch(v.getId())` or whatever you want to recognize which `View` fired click

Comment: The idea of using `instanceof` is nice, thanks for sharing. But as I say in the question, I want to use `OnTouchListener` that, unlike `onClickListener`, does not have an equivalent `android:onTouch` for example..